# My math prof does not have a proof for this: Existence of improper integrals for $\lim_{k\to \infty} \int_{a_k}^{b_k} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\alpha$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-writing, improper-integrals

In our analysis lecture our professor talked about the following **assumption** to which he said, that he does not have a proof:

> If for all sequences $(a_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}},(b_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$
>    with $a_k\to -\infty, b_k\to \infty$ already $\lim_{k\to \infty}
>  \int_{a_k}^{b_k} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\alpha$ holds (meaning that the
>    limit is distinct and it exists), then the following improper integrals
>    exist as well: $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\int_{-\infty}^0
>  f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ and it is $\alpha=\int_{-\infty}^0
>  f(x)\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Now the **problem**:

We only presuppose the convergence of $\int_{a_k}^{b_k} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$
. In doing so, constant sequences $a_k$ or $b_k$ are excluded since $a_k\to -\infty$ and  $b_k\to \infty$ have to hold.

How does the convergence of $ \int_{0}^{b_k} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\int_{a_k}^{0} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ follow now? Needless to say, the $0$ can of course be replaced by another constant.

If we assume the existence of two sequences $a_k$ or $b_k$, for which that does not apply, then it's probably possible to do a proof by contradiction (if one skillfully considers subsequences). Most likely a lot of cases have to be distinguished, because one does not know why both part-integrals $\int_{0}^{b_k} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\int_{a_k}^{0} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ not converge. They could be unbounded, or oscillating (or jump back and forth) or both.

Does someone here know how to prove the assumption or know where I can find such a proof on the internet? (Because my professor said that he doesn't have an obvious solution to this question)

Comment: Suppose there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a value $c_n>n$ such that $|\int_n^{c_n} f(x)dx|>\epsilon$.  So consider $\int_{-n}^{c_n} f(x)dx = \int_{-n}^{n} f(x)dx + \int_n^{c_n}f(x)dx$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: I think it would depend on how you treat certain improper integrals. If you allow Cauchy principal value integrals, then you could have (for example) $\int_{-1}^1f(x)\,dx=0$ while $\int_{-1}^0f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$ both are undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $b_k, c_k \geq 0$ be sequences such that $\lim_{k\to\infty} b_k = \lim_{k\to\infty} c_k = \infty$ and suppose that $b_k < c_k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. By assumption,

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_{b_k}^{c_k} f(x)~\mathrm dx = \lim_{k\to\infty}\left( \int_{-k}^{c_k} f(x)~\mathrm dx - \int_{-k}^{b_k} f(x)~\mathrm dx \right) = \alpha - \alpha = 0.$$

By the Cauchy criterion (cf [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Improper_integral)), this shows that $$\lim_{y\to\infty} \int_{0}^{y} f(x)~\mathrm d x $$
exists.

Comment: How would this proof treat a function such as $f(x)=1/x^3,$ $f(0)=0$?

Comment: Good point. I've edited my question to include a link to a definition of improper integral, one of its requirements is that the function should be integrable on every subinterval of the region that you define the improper integral over, so in our case for all $[a,b]\subseteq (-\infty,\infty)$. It seems to me that an assumption of this kind is usually incorporated into the definition of the improper Riemann integral. Would you disagree?

Comment: You want $-k$ instead of $-n$ above. Nice solution, +1.

Comment: @zhw of course, thanks.

Comment: I think you have the right approach here. The point is that it comes down to how the integrals are defined in the first place, which the question does not completely specify. Your way seems fairly standard, and if they do it the same, they'll be OK.